# Rails 6 - Strong Parameters - allowing array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am sending this simple hash as JSON to my controller:

```
{
    "cars": [
        { "rego": "ABC123" }
    ]
}
```

In the controller, I am trying to allow the array of cars for further processing.

I tried the following:

```
params.permit(:cars)
params.permit(cars: [])
params.permit(:cars, cars: [])
```

In every attempt I am not getting anything in my filtered params:

```
DEBUG -- : Unpermitted parameters: :cars, :car, :user_username, :user_token
=> <ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>
```

I am using RoR 6.0.2.1 with Ruby 2.6.5.

Comment: did you try passing it as the last attribute of the `permitted_params` list?

Comment: Are you sending that as params or in the body as JSON of the request? request params and body are 2 different things, can you post the log from rails when this controller method is being called?

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. You're asking us to help debug, but we can't duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try `params.permit(cars: [:rego])`

`params.permit(cars: [])` allows cars as an array of primitive values

```
{
    "cars": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

"[Strong Parameters](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)" has more information.